# Reactjs - libraries / logic needed for conditional drop down menus like Wordpress's admin dashboard?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am wanting to recreate the vertical menu behavior Wordpress' admin dashboard has to learn more about Reactjs states, modular components, and more. The behavior I'm am talking about is where you can hover over a sub menu, select it, and then you can see the parent menu selected with the sub menu below it.  Before I jump into coding I am looking for some pointers on how to create this efficiently and make it scalable.

Vide example of this Wordpress behavior:

https://i.imgur.com/hNFXYHW.mp4

I am still new to react but I am aware that there are React addons like the React router that can provide conditional logic where if you're on a certain URL you can trigger certain behaviors to happen. But I'm not sure if that's necessary to use at this point.

Is it advisable to use something like the React router for this type of behavior? Can this be mostly handled with vanilla Reactjs, bootstrap and CSS?

I'd like to make this functionality scalable so additional menu items added to the site could just drop into place like Wordpress plugins do.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please can you share what you have try so far ?

Comment: @johannchopin This is what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Vallamost/jyzgq0sk/ I've got the second menu that is supposed to sit under the Parent also hovering with the pop out menu. It needs to be styled to show up upon a child element being selected in the hover menu.